# Covariance term appears when not expected

Tags: variance, covariance, correlation

I am looking at a basic radar problem.  To skirt around sampling for the moment, I am "transmitting" a discrete signal, $$\mathbf{s}=\begin{bmatrix}f_1&f_2\end{bmatrix}^T$$

Assuming no attenuation, the signal is reflected from the target and picks up some noise so that, $$\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}f_2+W_2&f_1+W_1\end{bmatrix}^T,\qquad W_i\thicksim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_w^2)$$

The vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{s}$ are correlated to yield,
$$\mathbf{Y}=\begin{bmatrix}f_1^2+f_1W_1&2f_1f_2+f_2W_1+f_1W_2&f_2^2+f_2W_2\end{bmatrix}^T$$

The expected value of $Y_1$ for example is,
\begin{align*}
    \mathrm{E}[Y_1]&=\mathrm{E}[f_1^2+f_1W_1]\\
    &=f_1^2+f_1\,\mathrm{E}[W_1]\\
    &=f_1^2
\end{align*}

The expected value for $\mathbf{Y}$ is,
$$\mu_{\mathbf{Y}}=\begin{bmatrix}f_1^2&2f_1f_2&f_2^2\end{bmatrix}^T$$

The variance for $Y_i$ is solved according to,
\begin{equation*}
    \mathrm{var}(Y_i)=\mathrm{E}\left[(Y_i-\mathrm{E}[Y_i])^2\right]
\end{equation*}

I calculate the variance of $\mathbf{Y}$ and get,
\begin{equation*}
    \mathrm{var}(\mathbf{Y})=\begin{bmatrix}f_1^2\sigma_w^2&(f_1^2+f_2^2)\sigma_w^2&f_2^2\sigma_w^2\end{bmatrix}^T
\end{equation*}

I simulate this by creating several thousand realizations of $\mathbf{Y}=R_{\mathbf{SX}}(\tau)$ and then calculate the means and variances across all the $Y_1$, $Y_2$ and $Y_3$.

It all checks out nicely.  But then I figured if I looked at, say, $\mathrm{covar}(Y_1,Y_2)$, I should get zero.  But instead I get,
$$\mathrm{covar}(Y_1,Y_2)=\mathrm{E}\left[(Y_1-\mathrm{E}[Y_1])(Y_2-\mathrm{E}[Y_2])\right]=f_1f_2\sigma_w^2$$

Could someone please give me a tip as how I should think about this?

Comment: Don't you have to reflect $\bf s$ as well?

Comment: I need to think about that, but I can see that it makes sense to correlate "like" with "like" (i.e.: like if this was a matched filter).  

But even if I reflect $\mathbf{s}$, I still get non-zero terms for $\mathrm{covar}(Y_1,Y_2)$ and $\mathrm{covar}(Y_2,Y_3)$?

Is it because of the correlation that a dependence between adjacent $f_i$'s comes out or am I just looking at this entirely wrong?

Comment: Are you looking to find the peak of the correlation to determine the time delay? Is $\bf s$ a pseudo random/golay time signal? If so, I believe $x$ is does not appear in reverse order, but in the same order you sent $s$ (first sent, first received).

Comment: I am not that advanced yet.  I am really just trying to get my understanding of detection correct.  So the transmitted signal is generalised - it could be a square pulse, a time-bound sinusoid, etc.   Then, i am trying to figure out what we see at the detector, setup likelihood functions for (a) signal + noise present and (b) just noise present, then establish a likelihood ratio, and test against a threshold.  Going in, I was expecting everything to be independent... so my covariance matrix would have diagonal entries only... and then i build out the multivariate Gaussians for (a) and (b)...